# Lost my ios and www folders

Tags: ios, cordova

I have created ios project with cordova 4.1

The problem that when I have removed some plugins , the ios folder refreshed and all my works lost .

Its create new www and ios folders , there is any way to recover my last ios and www folders ?

Answer (score 0):

Create project expects a directory that does not exist.
See [cordova create project](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/#cordova-create-command) look for path.

Quoting:

> path: Directory which should not already exist. Cordova will create this directory. For more details on the directory structure, see below.

Comment: Cordova create new ios floder and replaced it with old ios folder which conrains all my work , can u explain more

Comment: Its possible to find it in trash ?

Comment: I don't have iOS device handy at this time to check. You should check if it is there. You may be in luck. I don't like this behavior for e.g. git won't allow cloning into an existing folder with same name. Cordova should prevent from accidental wiping existing.